# Getting error on input []: findDistance() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, sql, database, algorithm, sorting

The first part of my code is calculating the distance between two locations on Earth. The second part of my code is returning a list containing all of the cities stored in the database that are in the United States. The database is saved in a file named "city_data.db" containing a table named "cities" with columns ("country_code", "city_name", "region", "population", "latitude", "longitude"). Note that the country code for the United States is "us".

The third part of my code is returning a list containing all of the cities stored in the database that are in the United States sorted by their great circle distance from the city of Buffalo. Use (42.8864, -78.8784) for the latitude/longitude of Buffalo

I am getting error on input []: findDistance() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given. What am I doing wrong?

```
import sqlite3
import math
conn = sqlite3.connect("city_data.db")
c = conn.cursor()
conn.commit()

#Part 1
def great_circle_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    radius = 6371

    dlat = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
    dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)
    a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) \
        * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
    d = radius * c

    return d

#Part 2
def get_us_cities():
    get_city = c.execute("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE country_code = 'us'").fetchall()
    return [x for x in get_city]

#Part 3
def findDistance():
    citieslist = get_us_cities()
    lat1 = 42.8864 
    lon1 = -78.8784
    lat2 = citieslist[4]
    lon2= citieslist[5]
    distance = great_circle_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
    return distance 

def closest_cities():
    array = get_us_cities()
    array.sort(key = findDistance)
    return array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing

```
array.sort(key = findDistance)
```

That means that the sorting algorithm is using `findDistance()` to find a "key" for each value it's sorting. Basically, it takes a list, does `findDistance()` for every item in that list, and then sorts the list according to the return values. As such, `array.sort()` expects that whatever it's given as a `key` will be able to take one value and spit out another value that can be used for sorting.

I don't know how you're structuring your database, or what format your array is going to be in, but let's assume for this example that each item in the array is a list, with indexes corresponding to the columns you listed (for example, "latitude" would be index `4`, "longitude would be index `5`, etc). Then, you'd want to rewrite `findDistance()` to take one of those as a parameter:

```
def findDistance(city):
    lat1 = 42.8864 
    lon1 = -78.8784
    lat2 = city[4]    # notice how we're using the variable that was passed in,
    lon2 = city[5]    #   instead of accessing get_us_cities()
    distance = great_circle_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
    return distance
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more of why I want to pass city as a parameter to finddistance() instead of trying to access latitude and longitude from get_us_cities(). Because somehow, your code gives me the correct output.

Comment: Don't forget, `get_us_cities()` gives you the entire list of cities (or a list of lists, in this case) - when you call `array.sort()`, you're doing it on an array that you *already initialized to that list of cities*. The `sort()` function will automatically apply the key to each element of that list, by passing that element into `findDistance()`. So, `get_us_cities()` is already involved by the time `findDistance()` is called - you don't have to bring it in again.